# File comparision using shell script

Tags: shell

I have two files named file1 and file2.

Content of file1 --->
Hello/Good/Morning
World/India

Content of file2 --->
Hello/Good/Morning
World/China

I need to check if the contents of these files are equal or not.Since both the files have "Hello/Good/Morning" in common it should print "EQUAL" as per my requirement.I have written a code for this:

```
file1=/app/webmcore1/Demo/FORLOOP/Kasturi/xyz/pqr.txt
file2=/app/webmcore1/Demo/FORLOOP/Prashast/xyz/pqr.txt 
IFS=` ` 

for i in cat $file1 
do 
    if [ "$i" != '' ]; then 
        echo "$i" 

        for j in cat $file2
        do 
            if [ "$j" != '' ]; then 
                echo "$j" 

                if [[ $i -eq $j ]]; then 
                    echo "EQUAL" 
                fi 
            fi 
       done 
    fi 
done
```

But it is not displaying the output properly.

Comment: `I have written a code for this` Please share the code, if not classified.

Comment: file1=/app/webmcore1/Demo/FORLOOP/Kasturi/xyz/pqr.txt file2=/app/webmcore1/Demo/FORLOOP/Prashast/xyz/pqr.txt         IFS=` `                                                          for i in `cat $file1`                                             do if [ "$i" != '' ];                                            then echo "$i"                                                    for j in `cat $file2`                                              do if [ "$j" != '' ];then                                          echo "$j" if [[ $i -eq $j ]];  then echo "EQUAL"  fi fi done fi done

Comment: Don't put code in the comments, put it in the question itself by editing the question.

Comment: You are `cat`-ing file2 for each word in file1. Very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

`diff` compares files, line by line. If `diff filename` outputs anything, the files are different.

If the output of `diff` is empty, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

There already is a tool to compare files, it's called `diff` (and actually much more powerful than just deciding equal or not, but can be used for this).

```
diff -q file1 file2 >/dev/null && echo "EQUAL"
```

If you also want to to print return something in case the files are not equal:

```
diff -q file1 file2 >/dev/null && echo "EQUAL" || echo "NOT EQUAL"
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the files are "equal" if they have any single word in common?

```
result=$(
    comm -12 <(tr '[:space:]' '\n' <file1 | sort)  <(tr '[:space:]' '\n' <file2 | sort) 
)
[[ -n $result ]] && echo EQUAL
```

Or, just in bash

```
words=( $(< file1) )

for word in $(< file2); do 
    if [[ " ${words[*]} " == *" $word "* ]]; then 
        echo "EQUAL due to $word"
        break
    fi
done
```

```
EQUAL due to Hello/Good/Morning
```